# Has this Force superpower been shown before in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In *The Mandalorian Chapter 7: The Reckoning*,

> baby Yoda was shown to completely heal a wound using The Force (the final result was like the wound was never there). He even neutralized a strong poison in the system.

I didn't know that a force sensitive was capable of this. Has this Force superpower been shown before in the entire Star Wars universe (including Legends)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Yes.**

This "superpower" had been used pretty extensively in Legends, with multiple instances set during the Old Republic and retconned to have been used in the films. For example, Legends dictated that in *A New Hope*, when Luke is attacked by Tusken Raiders, Obi-Wan uses force healing to help him recover.

In canon, this ability appeared a few days after Chapter 7 of *The Mandalorian* in

> *The Rise of Skywalker*, when Rey uses it to heal an injured giant worm creature. Towards the end of the film, Ben Solo uses force healing to revive Rey from the dead, at the cost of his own life (and the hopes of Reylo stans).

According to the visual dictionary for that film, the former learned of a variation of this ability in one of the ancient Jedi texts, although this use of the ability is for healing kyber crystals as opposed to living beings.